# What function describes an area of projection of a circle that is tilting so that we start with the area of a circle and end up with a straight line?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

My question is simple. I would like to know the function that describes the area of a projection of a circle on a plane (meaning something like an area of a shadow of the circle on a paper) based on the amount by which the circle is tilted around y axis. So I imagine we start with an area of a circle and end up with straight line with zero area.

Comment: the projection is an ellipse, with semi-major axis $r$ (the radius of the circle), and semi-minor axis $r\cos\theta$ (or $r\sin\theta$ depending on how you measure the angle).

Comment: Actually I wonder how an area is changing when tilting a circle. Is the change of an area based on the amount of tilt linear? Or is it sinusoidal? Or is it some totally different function?

Comment: As mentioned by @yoyo the semi-minor axis length is $r\cos\theta$ and the semi-major axis length is $r$ so the area you seek is $\pi r^2\cos\theta$. Observe that for $\theta =0$ you recover the equation for the area of a circle as expected.